# basic lexical analyzer that reads a text file as input and writes all the "tokens" to an output file line by line

Tags: c++, parsing

```
     writing a very basic lexical analyzer in standard
    C++ (std usage is allowed) that reads a text file
    as input and writes all the "tokens" to an output
    file line by line
    ● All items that are separated by white space are
    tokens
    ● White space includes
    ● Space(s)
    ● Newlines
    ● Tabs

    Input file having this

        if (x > 50)
        x=0

    Output file should be like this

        if

        (

        x

        >

        50

        )

        x

        =

        0



Edit 3
```

Ok so im almost there i have made an input file that takes whatever is written in it and then tokenizes it and shows on the screen. an output file is generated bt when it shows this output Output tokens 0033F8C8  i thinks its the array address. now all i need to do is store the output being shown on the screen should go into the output text file and on the screen it should print see your output file your inputs are tokenized.

code edit 3

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using std::ifstream;

#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

const int MAX_CHARS_PER_LINE = 512;
const int MAX_TOKENS_PER_LINE = 20;
const char* const DELIMITER = " ";

int main()
{
    // create a file-reading object
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("input.txt"); // open a file
    if (!infile.good())
        return 1; // exit if file not found

    ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open("output.txt");
    if (!outfile)
    {
        cout << "error opening fiLe";
    }

    // read each line of the file
    while (!infile.eof())
    {
        // read an entire line into memory
        char buf[MAX_CHARS_PER_LINE];
        infile.getline(buf, MAX_CHARS_PER_LINE);

        // parse the line into blank-delimited tokens
        int n = 0; // a for-loop index

        // array to store memory addresses of the tokens in buf
        const char* token[MAX_TOKENS_PER_LINE] = {}; // initialize to 0

        // parse the line
        token[0] = strtok(buf, DELIMITER); // first token
        if (token[0]) // zero if line is blank
        {
            for (n = 1; n < MAX_TOKENS_PER_LINE; n++)
            {
                token[n] = strtok(0, DELIMITER); // subsequent tokens
                if (!token[n]) break; // no more tokens
            }
        }

        // process (print) the tokens
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) // n = #of tokens
            cout << "Token[" << i << "] = " << token[i] << endl;
        cout << endl;



        outfile<< "Output tokens" <<token;
        infile.close();
        outfile.close();


    }


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Add some code, so we can help where you get stuck.

Comment: use `strtok` or `regular expression`

Comment: @KirChou: `strtok` is evil, it modifies the C-Style string that is passed to it.

Comment: Thanks alot @ThomasMatthews ; whatever i write in the input file simplifies by converting into tokens, apart from telling it either it is a operator or identifier or anything else. i want to link a file that would open up, convert whitespace tabs and spaces into tokens, then save the new output in the other text file

Comment: Do you want to write the program or do you want somebody else to write it?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews could you please look at my edit 3 and the new code i have done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have tagged your question as C++, I recommend using the C++ language features as they are safer (less defects injected) than C.

For example, replace `char *` with `std::string`.  The `std::string` has more features for lexing or searching than the C-Style string functions (`str*()`).

For your projects, I don't recommend using regular expressions.  Getting them to work correctly may take you longer than implement a simple lexer.

**Edit 1**
For more specific help, please edit your question with the syntax rules of the language you are parsing.

One simple technique is to isolate "words" or *identifiers* from symbols.

Also read up on [Backus-Naur notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form)

Your issue is too complicated (in the big picture) to be answered in StackOverflow.

**Edit 2 - Example**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

int main(void)
{
  std::ifstream input("input.txt");
  if (!input)
  {
    std::cerr << "Error opening \"input.txt\".\r\n";
    return 1;
  }

  // Read the file.
  std::string input_text;
  while (std::getline(input, input_text))
  {
    static const char white_space[] = " \t";
    static const char identifier_letters[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    std::string::size_type position = 0;

    if (input_text.length() == 0)
    {
      continue; // Empty line
    }

    // Skip white space.
    position = input_text.find_first_not_of(white_space, 0);

    if ((position == std::string::npos)            
    {
      continue; // Blank line.
    }

    // Check if the first (non-whitespace character) is a
    //    valid identifier letter
    if (std::isalpha(input_text[position]))
    {
       // First character is a letter.
       // Find the end of the identifier.
       std::string::size_type identifier_end_posn = 0;
       identifier_end_posn = input_text.find_first_not_of(identifier_letters, position);
       if (identifier_end_posn != std::string::npos)
       {
         const int identifier_length = identifier_end_posn - position + 1;
         std::string identifier = input_text.substr(position, identifier_length);
         cout << identifier << "\n";
         continue;
       }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

You will need to augment the above code to look for symbols and numbers.